Python multiprocessing.pool apply_async callback function fails to re-order output data
I am using the multiprocessing.pool apply_async function to process some video data via a computer vision algorithm, and the current strategy to speed up the process, since the algorithm has no memory, is to split the video in smaller sections, and process them in parallel.
To parallelise the process, the relevant function is packaged into a "worker" function which is then used in the apply_async method of the multiprocessing.pool.Pool class. Because apply_async returns results roughly by order of completion, and the video sequence must instead remain in the original order, the various outputs are re-ordered after the pool is closed and joined. This is done by assigning a sequential identifying number to each worker function, which is packaged into a tuple together with the results data array as the worker function output.
With this identifying number, the callback function assigns the output data array to the empty item with corresponding index in a previously-initialised list.
The code is as follows:
import pandas
import multiprocessing.pool
import traceback


def myFunction(video_file_path, frame_range) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    ...
    return data_frame


def worker(video_file_path, frame_range, process_nr):
    try:
        result = myFunction(video_file_path, frame_range)
        return process_nr, result
    except Exception as ex:  # the following error handling should not matter, but...
        tb = sys.exception().__traceback__
        print(f"error @ worker {process_nr} on {video_file_path}")
        print(f"Exception {type(ex)}: {ex}\nTraceback"
              f"\n{''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))}")
        return process_nr, None


def log_result(result):
    result_list[result[0]] = result[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_size = 8
    frame_ranges = [...]  # handled by some slicing function
    result_list = [None] * len(frame_ranges)

    with multiprocessing.pool.Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        for n, fcnk in enumerate(frame_ranges):
            pool.apply_async(worker, args=("C:\\some\\video\\path", fcnk, n),
                             callback=log_result)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    results_dataframe = result_list[0]
    for n in range(1, len(result_list)):
        results_dataframe = pandas.merge(results_dataframe, result_list[n], how='outer')
    results_dataframe.to_csv("C:\\some\\save\\path","some_save_name.csv")
    

... and this runs perfectly fine on my Windows 10 desktop PC in PyCharm IDE, with a Python 3.11.6 conda environment. It behaves exactly as expected:
The results are saved in a .csv file, with each line corresponding to the data from one frame, and all lines/frames in the correct order in the final csv file.
However, when I run it on a remote cluster running Ubuntu, the results are completely jumbled, with lines/frames from one frame slice intermixed with lines/frames of another in the final csv file.
Is this some absurd race condition due to simultaneous writing on an unallocated list, or some other bug/oversight in my code? I am currently running some tests on the remote server, but I only have a text terminal and it will take some time.

Small update: I have given up on solving this issue, and simply process multiple files in parallel which are saved to file independently of each other, instead of slicing each file. The issue itself may still be interesting, so I will leave it up.

Maybe force Ubuntu to use a spawning context rather than forking, but I don't see a problem with the multiprocessing code which would necessarily cause this. Also maybe check result_list before merging. Not critical, but I would likely specify nonlocal result_list inside log_result for clarity.

@Aaron Don't you mean global result_list?

In don't immediately see any issue with your code but there is a simpler and safer solution.
You want to execute a myFunction function (which we assume to be thread safe, you should check this) concurrently on a set of ordered inputs frame_ranges. Additionally, you want the results to remain in the same order as the input list of frame_ranges.
For this purpose, you can use the pool.map() method. This would look like this:
import multiprocessing.pool
import sys
import traceback
from functools import partial

import pandas


def myFunction(frame_range, video_file_path) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    ...
    return data_frame


def worker(frame_range, video_file_path):
    try:
        result = myFunction(frame_range, video_file_path)
        return result
    except Exception as ex:  # the following error handling should not matter, but...
        tb = sys.exception().__traceback__
        print(f"error @ worker on {video_file_path}")
        print(f"Exception {type(ex)}: {ex}\nTraceback"
              f"\n{''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))}")
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_size = 8
    frame_ranges = [...]  # handled by some slicing function

    _worker = partial(worker, video_file_path="C:\\some\\video\\path")

    with multiprocessing.pool.Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        result_list = pool.map(_worker, frame_ranges)

    results_dataframe = result_list[0]
    for n in range(1, len(result_list)):
        results_dataframe = pandas.merge(results_dataframe, result_list[n], how='outer')
    results_dataframe.to_csv("C:\\some\\save\\path","some_save_name.csv")

The pool.map() method automatically handle the gathering or results in the ordered list, you don't have to do it yourself anymore. Also, you don't have to close or join the pool in this version since the .map() call is a synchronous call, i.e it will wait for the completion of the tasks before the pool can terminate. I reordered the arguments of your function to be able to use partial in order to freeze some of the constant input parameter (the video file path).
If the myFunction function is thread safe this should give you a correct result.

FYI, close and join are actually recommended as pool.__exit__ calls pool.terminate without waiting for async tasks. This isn't needed for non-async calls in your case but the case of using apply_async does require it.

You are right, I modified my answer.

Thanks for the feedback, since it is a safer way to get ordered results it might fix the problem, but I cannot verify this as of now. I will get back to this as soon as I can.
